# How do I delete values from a column based on a Hierarchy in a given table?

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2012

In Table 1, I have customer ID and the list of Items the customer ID has purchased.

**Table 1**

```
Customer ID | Item Code
------------------------
 1000       |  10
 1000       |  20 
 1000       |  30
 1000       |  40
 2000       |  10
 2000       |  60
 2000       |  90
 2000       |  100
------------------------
```

In another table I have a Hierarchy as below

**Table 2**

```
This has precedence | Over This
---------------------------------
      30            |     10
      20            |     40
      60            |     90
      100           |     60
---------------------------------
```

I want to add a result column in `Table 1` which will, for example , for Customer 1000, eliminate 10 by 30 and 40 by 20 based on table 2.

Case 1: The 10 should be replaced by 30 only for Customer 1000 as there is a 30 present in the column 'Item Code' for Customer 1000 and not for Customer 2000.

Case 2: For Customer 2000, 60 should be replaced by 90 and 90 should be replaced by 100 for both rows.

So Ideally, Final result should be as follows-

---

> Customer ID | Item Code | Final Code

---

> ```
>  1000       |  10   | 30
>  1000       |  20   | 20
>  1000       |  30   | 30
>  1000       |  40   | 20
>  2000       |  10   | 10 (This is not replaced!)
>  2000       |  60   | 100
>  2000       |  90   | 100
>  2000       |  100  | 100
> ```

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating the query as OP got updated and shows recursion.

If you want to **add a column** in Table 1 to show precedence data. Here how you can accomplish it.

```
   ALTER TABLE Table1
     ADD Result int
   GO

       ;WITH CTE([This has Precedence], [Over This]) 
       AS
       (
       --First find the top level members
       --These are the items which does't have any precedence
       SELECT T2A.[This has Precedence], T2A.[Over This] FROM dbo.Table2 T2A
       LEFT JOIN dbo.Table2 T2B
       ON T2A.[This has Precedence] = T2B.[Over This]
       WHERE T2B.[Over This] IS NULL

       UNION ALL
       --Now call the lower level members and join with the CTE
       SELECT CTE.[This has Precedence],  T2.[OVER THIS] 
       FROM dbo.Table2 T2
       INNER JOIN CTE ON T2.[This has Precedence] = CTE.[Over This]
       )

  --Now use the recursive CTE to find the correct precedence member.
   UPDATE T1
   SET Result = ISNULL(T1x.[Item Code], T1.[Item Code])
   FROM Table1 T1
    LEFT JOIN CTE T2
            ON T1.[Item Code] = T2.[Over This]
    LEFT JOIN Table1 T1x
            ON T2.[This has Precedence] = T1x.[Item Code]
           AND T1.CID = T1x.CID
  GO
```

Answer (score 0):

Doing an update, assuming those are your real column names:

```
ALTER TABLE Table1
ADD result int

UPDATE a
SET result = [Item Code] - [This has precedence]
from Table1 a
inner join Table2 b
on a.[Item Code] = b.[Over this]
```

Answer (score 0):

update2: based on question update

```
select a.*,ISNULL(d.[This has precedence],a.ItemCode) as [Final Code]
 from table1 a left join 
 (select b.[This has precedence],b.[over this],c.customerID from 
 (select ISNULL(q.[This has precedence],p.[This has precedence]) as [This has precedence],p.[Over This] from table2 p left join table2 q
on p.[This has precedence]=q.[Over This])
  b 
 inner join  table1 c on C.ItemCode=b.[This has precedence]) d
  on a.ItemCode=d.[Over This]
 and d.customerID=a.CustomerID
```

update: based on recent comment by asker

> I missed to add a clause in the question. the 10 should be replaced by
>   30 only when there is a 30 present in the column Item Code for
>   Customer 1000.

for a result like

```
Customer ID | Result
------------------
 1000       | 30
-------------------------
 1000       | 20 
--------------------------
 1000       | 20
--------------------------
 2000       |  10
```

updated query is like:

```
select DISTINCT a.CustomerID,ISNULL(d.[This has precedence],a.ItemCode) as result
 from table1 a left join 
 (select b.[This has precedence],b.[over this],c.customerID from table2 b 
 inner join  table1 c on C.ItemCode=b.[This has precedence]) d
  on a.ItemCode=d.[Over This]
 and d.customerID=a.CustomerID
```

and for a result like

```
Customer ID | Item Code| Result
------------------
 1000       |  10   | 30
-------------------------
 1000       |  20   |NULL 
--------------------------
 1000       |  30   |NULL
--------------------------
1000        |  40   |20
--------------------------
 2000       |  10   | NULL
```

use below query:

```
select a.*,d.[This has precedence] as result
 from table1 a left join 
 (select b.[This has precedence],b.[over this],c.customerID from table2 b 
 inner join  table1 c on C.ItemCode=b.[This has precedence]) d
  on a.ItemCode=d.[Over This]
 and d.customerID=a.CustomerID
```

> if you want a result like this
>
> ```
> Customer ID | Item Code| Result
> ------------------
>  1000       |  10   | 30
> -------------------------
>  1000       |  20   |NULL 
> --------------------------
>  1000       |  30   |NULL
> --------------------------
> 1000        |  40   |20
> --------------------------
>  2000       |  10   | 30
> ```
>
> then below query will work
>
> ```
> select a.*,b.[This has precedence] as result
>  from table1 a left join table2 b on a.ItemCode=b.[Over This]
> ```
>
> If you want to replace rows and get distinct values
>
> ```
> Customer ID | Item Code
> ------------------
>  1000       |  30  
> -------------------
>  1000       |  20  
> -------------------
>  2000       |  30
> ```
>
> the use below query
>
> ```
> update a
> set a.ItemCode=b.[This has precedence] 
>  from table1 a left join table2 b on a.ItemCode=b.[Over This]
> ```
>
> followed by
>
> ```
> select * from table1
> ```
>
> if you do not want to update table1 and simply get the above output
>   then
>
> ```
> select DISTINCT a.CustomerID,b.[This has precedence] as result
>  from table1 a left join table2 b on a.ItemCode=b.[Over This]
> ```

Comment: I used your query and its not working. Even though the customer does not have a particular Item code in his table, that gets added in the result as it is a part of the heirarchy table